# Numpy loadtxt Behavior change with Python 3

Tags: csv, python-3.x, numpy

I have some code that has been working fine in Python 2.7 using numpy's loadtxt function to read in a csv file into a numpy array.  The file can be seen [here](http://www.andrewhowe.com/INDEX_20140101.csv).  I use this command

```
 inp = numpy.loadtxt(filename, dtype=str, delimiter=',',skiprows=1
```

With this, I get this in python 2.7

```
array([['BKNIF', '01-Jan-2014', '11418.9', '11432.55', '11361', '11385.6',
    '0'],
   ['BSESN', '01-Jan-2014', '21222.19', '21244.35', '21133.82',
    '21140.48', '0'],
   ['DXY', '01-Jan-2014', '80.21', '80.24', '80.16', '80.19', '0'],
   ['FBV', '01-Jan-2014', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']], 
  dtype='|S11')
```

However, with python 3.3, I'm getting

```
array([["b'BKNIF'", "b'01-Jan-2014'", "b'11418.9'", "b'11432.55'",
        "b'11361'", "b'11385.6'", "b'0'"],
       ["b'BSESN'", "b'01-Jan-2014'", "b'21222.19'", "b'21244.35'",
        "b'21133.82'", "b'21140.48'", "b'0'"],
       ["b'DXY'", "b'01-Jan-2014'", "b'80.21'", "b'80.24'", "b'80.16'",
        "b'80.19'", "b'0'"],
       ["b'FBV'", "b'01-Jan-2014'", "b'0'", "b'0'", "b'0'", "b'0'", "b'0'"]], 
      dtype='<U14')
```

Note how the import has inserted the double quote around every item, and the b in front.  It has also apparently decide to code it differently.  Even if I use `dtype='|S11'` instead of `dtype=str`, I get the same behavior.

Please don't comment on why am I using numpy loadtxt for this, or if you think my use of loadtxt is inefficient.  Right now, I need help with figuring out why the behavior changed, and how to fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [20]: m=loadtxt(fname, dtype='S20', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

In [21]: m.astype(str)
Out[21]: 
array([['BKNIF', '01-Jan-2014', '11418.9', '11432.55', '11361', '11385.6',
        '0'],
       ['BSESN', '01-Jan-2014', '21222.19', '21244.35', '21133.82',
        '21140.48', '0'],
       ['DXY', '01-Jan-2014', '80.21', '80.24', '80.16', '80.19', '0'],
       ['FBV', '01-Jan-2014', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['NSEI', '01-Jan-2014', '6323.8', '6327.2', '6298.25', '6301.65',
        '0'],
       ['NVOT', '01-Jan-2014', '30783.764', '2313498.5', '30783.764',
        '2313498.5', '0'],
       ['RUI', '01-Jan-2014', '1027.14', '1030.97', '1027.14', '1030.364',
        '0'],
       ['RUT', '01-Jan-2014', '1160.64', '1165.64', '1160.64', '1163.637',
        '0'],
       ['SENSEX', '01-Jan-2014', '21222.19', '21244.35', '21133.82',
        '21140.48', '0']], 
      dtype='<U20')
```

but still the elements are `numpy.bytes_`:

```
m[0][0]
Out[22]: b'BKNIF'

type(m[0][0])
Out[23]: numpy.bytes_
```

i think it's just looks not pretty?

Comment: Whoo!  Can you tell me why that is suddenly required?  I have been unable to find any documentation about changes to loadtxt...

Comment: @Dr.Drew require what?

Comment: with python2.7, the same code and import file comes into python without requiring the forced .astype(str).

Comment: @Dr.Drew i dunno neither... just tried it out. m[0][0] is `numpy.string_' on my win7 py2.7